# Returning value adjacent to search using vLookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I've been rusty and I keep fumbling with the equations. I'm trying to use Vlookup to return a name from a different sheet

the formula i use is:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,ListA!A2:D50,1,0),"")`

I keep getting error: Did not find value `'43132'` in VLOOKUP evaluation. ...did I get the syntax wrong?

Sheet: ListB
B1 = `Feb 1, 2014`

Sheet: ListA
Column A or 1 has the list of names (value I was hoping it would return)
Column D has the list of dates

May I ask for help please?

Comment: why are you looking in A:D if you only want to return from column A?

Comment: Ahhh i thought the range should include the column it would return the value of? I tried limiting it to Column D though, the value it returns is the Date instead of the name 

=(VLOOKUP(B1,ListA!D2:D50,1,0),"")

Comment: Vlookup expects the value that is being found in the most left column. You will need to do an index match.

Comment: =INDEX(LIstA!A2:A4,MATCH(B2,LIstA!D2:D4,0))

Comment: ^^With example range A2:A4

Comment: Vlookup works by looking for the matching value in the 1st column of your range and returning a value to the right of that.  This is why the range A1:D is not working because column A does not contain the date value you're looking up.  Your only option is to insert a column before A and copy column D to that column and then do the vlookup with A1:B,2 or if you don't want to change the list you can use index match which is now above my comment because I'm slow at typing :).

Comment: Thanks Scott and QHarr! Will try it

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much for your help Qharr, Gordon and Scott :)